# Create new item in Ember

Tags: ember.js

im playing with the ember starter kit bloggr just to get familiarized with its stuff.

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/AkUpOho/1/edit)

In the Posts section I want to be able to create a new post. This is the relevant changes according to the original code.

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  model: function() {
return posts;  },  
events: {
  createPost: function(){
    var posts = this.modelFor('posts');
    var post = posts.pushObject({
      id: posts.length
    });
    this.transitionTo('/edit', post);
  }    
}});
```

and the event gets fired when

```
 <tr><th><a href="#" {{action createPost}}>New Post</a></th></tr>
 <tr><th>Recent Posts</th></tr>
```

If you try to create a new post, there's clearly a new instance of posts (0 and 1 are hardcoded so you get post id=2) but the edit template is not rendered. 
The only way to get to do something is to first load post 0 or 1 and then click on the new one (just visible by "**by**") and edit it.

What I'd like to achieve is to get a fresh new edit instance of the template so I can set the fields for the newly created post.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

G'day Daniel

Here you go this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/AkUpOho/14/edit) is working.

To get this working I added [Ember Data](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/beta/latest) and the fixture adapter

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;
```

Then I turned the post object that came with the example into fixture data.

```
App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
 title: "Rails is Omakase"
}, { 
 title: "The Parley Letter"
}];
```

Next I adding a new posts route.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
 this.resource('about');
 this.resource('posts', function() {
   this.route('new');
   this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
 });
});
```

Then added a link-to to that new route.

```
{{#link-to 'posts.new'}}New Post{{/link-to}}
```

In the `PostsNewRoute` model hook I creat a 'post'. The template uses the `{{partial 'post/edit'}}` to reuse the edit form.

Here is the PostsNewRoute code showing the save action.

```
 App.PostsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      return this.get('store').createRecord('post');
    },
    actions: {
      save: function() {
        this.modelFor('postsNew').save();
        this.transitionTo('posts.index');
      }
    }
  });
```

If you have any more questions let me know.

Cheers

Comment: thanks a lot! and the question is answered but I'd like to ask you something else. With the addition you made, new posts get a route like `posts/fixture-0`, while hardcoded array is as intended `posts/0` etc. Is there a way to fix this? Secondly, can we fire the "save" action with the button "done" instead of having another button? I realized you changed `.commit()` for `.save()`. If you don't have the time it's fine, as I've said you managed to solve the issue! Thanks again.